# Convert Excel HTML to cleaner HTML

Tags: excel, html-table, excel-2003

Is there an easy way to convert the output of Excel 2003's Save to HTML option to something more 'friendly'? I have an Excel document with about 20 columns and 50 rows.

Throughout the saved HTML file I have obsolete HTML (example: `<table x:str border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=1366 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:1025pt'>`), in line styles, and empty cells all over the place.

I'd like something less 'table-y'. Is there a way to either force Excel 2003 to save it using more CSS and less tables or a way to convert tables to `div`s more easily than going through the HTML file by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Dreamweaver, you can use its markup cleaner tool...which I believe is designed for this kind of thing.

Create a new HTML document in Dreamweaver, copy and paste your code in and use the cleanup tool.

Here's one guide I find, but you could probably find better if it doesn't help:

http://www.articleonlinedirectory.com/656381/cleaning-up-unwanted-formatting-dreamweaver.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If still of interest, Tidy shall neatly do the task in hand!

It seems to be somewhat without support so expect to find some troubles to make it useful for your needs.

Anyway, for POC you can rely on a on-line version found at http://infohound.net/tidy/.

Just checking the 'Clean' option leaving everything as-is would lead to a result close to your expectations.

Regards and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Open the html file in browser and run some code in console is a way, a rough example:

```js
var whiteList = ["rowspan", "colspan"];

[...document.querySelectorAll("table")].forEach(table => {
  rmAttr(table);
  [...table.querySelectorAll("tr")].forEach(tr => {
    rmAttr(tr);
    [...tr.querySelectorAll("td")].forEach(td => {
      rmAttr(td);
    });
  });
  console.log(table.outerHTML);
});

function rmAttr(dom) {
  [...dom.attributes].forEach(attr => {
    if (!~whiteList.indexOf(attr.name)) {
      dom.removeAttribute(attr.name);
    }
  });
}
```